# How to ping proxies ? ie in IP:PORT format

Tags: vb.net, sockets, asynchronous, ping, proxies

Well I decided to try make a proxy checker, like Charion or Elite proxy checker. These programs accept large lists of proxies in the IP:PORT format, ping them tell you the response time

see the screenshot of Elite Proxy Checker, im trying to make a simplified version of this program. http://i52.tinypic.com/a57slh.jpg

I investigated and made my checker using Ping.SendAsync(ip, timeout, ip) method.
It was only afterwards that I discovered that you can only Ping IP's using this method, not the ports as well.

Ive spent a few hours trying to find the correct class/methods in order to be able to ping ports, reading different forum posts from experts they say its impossible to ping ports only IPS, can only use sockets to try open a connection with the port.

However, I have seen programs that people have coded in VB.NET that ping in the IP:PORT format, ie lets you choose timeout, tells timeout, etc.

**My question is , what classes methods should I be using to do this ?**

Im pretty sure its not sockets... theyve got to be pinging the individual ports as well somehow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

(I code for a hobby, im not a pro, so sorry if I make glaring errors)

Comment: What makes you sure that the programs you have seen don´t try to connect to the port (with a timeout) for their ip:port pings?

Comment: hey, sorry about the late reply, good old xmas.... I was under the impression that you cannot ping Port, only an IP .... ive found some old VB6 code that does what I want, now I just have to try convert it....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `tcpping`, here is the Windows version:

http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php

Comment: thanks for the link, ill look into it........ I was after a solution in .net though (to intergrate into my small apps)